# Visual Studio Code - No error for non-existent object property

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I do not get red squiggles when trying to reference a non-existent property from a required package (i.e. another javascript file) in my javascript file. VSC will show the object signature when I hover over it with cursor, but will not show a visual indication that the property I'm trying to reference does not exist. Without the visual indication I am only catching these problems at runtime, which is less efficient.

E.g.:

`TypeError: rtdb_refs.ref is not a function`

As far as I know, that should have generated a visual error in the IDE after I typed it.

I've tried looking through all my IDE settings but haven't found anything that stands out.